# Transitive Implication Converse

Tags: logic

1-**i tried if statement with one condition but what about the following?:**
*how can i converse and Contrapositive a transitive implication like :*

question:`if a>b and b>c implies a>c`

Comment: Try writing the implication as "if ... then ...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transitivity of a relation $R$ can be stated in two ways:

1. $\forall x,y,z\,((xRy \land yRz)\to xRz)$,
2. $\forall x,z\,(\exists z\,(xRy \land yRz)\to xRz)$.

Their converses are:

1. $\forall x,y,z\,(xRz\to (xRy \land yRz))$,
2. $\forall x,z\,(xRz\to \exists z\,(xRy \land yRz))$.

Their contrapositives are:

1. $\forall x,y,z\,(\neg xRz\to \neg (xRy \land yRz))$,
2. $\forall x,z\,(\neg xRz\to \neg\exists z\,(xRy \land yRz))$,

Both are both equivalent to:

$$\forall x,y,z\,(\neg xRz\to (\neg xRy \lor \neg yRz)).$$

Comment: To what understood. Converse is : if a>c implies a>b and b>c . Contraapositive is :if a<c implies a<b and b<c ????? am i right?

Comment: You're right about the converse, but not right about the contrapositive, unless the relation is total (= linear ordering). And in any case, if the relation really is "<", less than, then the negation of $a<c$ is $c\le a$, not  $c<a$.

Comment: i applied what u said . For the Converse i switched the Conclusion with the Hypothesis . You mentioned converse is ∀x,y,z(xRz→(xRy∧yRz)); So why i am Wrong???????

Comment: The converse that you wrote in your first comment is correct. Sorry, I was missing a "not" in my first reply. Fixed it.

Comment: So according to the original one : if a>b and b>c implies a>c  . The Contrapositive has to be: if c=>a implies b =>a or c =>b ????i hope am right now ???

Comment: Yes that's right :) Two points: (1) when you have to use two characters to write "less than or equal", the "<" comes first: `a<=b`. The other order looks like it's trying to be an arrow. (2) when using this site, writing mathematics as if you did it on a typewriter or a 1960s computer looks horrible and people will think worse of you, because MathJax makes it possible to write beautiful-looking mathematics in a modern style.

Comment: PS If you ask a question on the site and an answer is useful, give it a vote.

Comment: Brian, firstly am so sorrry for the Typing order coz i dont know about the MathJax . i have been in this site may be 2 hours or so ... For the Vote i am ready to put a million Vote but actually i dont know where ??? Again 4give me first then be patient with me if you please .... Thanks .

Comment: No problem. I just meant for future reference. Here's a MathJax tutorial/quick reference: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. I'm not sure how you "accept an answer as the correct one", but give an answer a vote, click the up arrow above the number to the left of the answer.

Comment: Mission has done ........

Comment: Your tip is appreciated, lol, thanks.